# replacing words from string (.NET)

Tags: .net, vb.net

i have this text in string,

```
<img src="https://scontent-yyz1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t45.1600-4/43283458_6107883208189_8123813812978581504_n.png?_nc_cat=108&oh=1f88c51fa75c03ec2923655cc0b8e0ce&oe=5C14EE74" height="500"
```

i want to get only URL from the string. in other words i want to remove `<img src="`
and `" height="500"` from string.

I've tried the following:

```
Dim cleanString As String = Replace(RichTextBox1.Text, "<img src=""", "").Replace(""" height=""500""", "")
```

But this doesn't work. There is nothing in `cleanstring`; event is executed on Button Click.

Comment: RichTextBox1.Text.Replace("<img src=""", "").Replace(""" height=""500""", "")

Comment: @CruleD Nop. Not working

Comment: It would be very strange that `cleanString` is empty because Replace returns the original string if it doesn't find any matches. Can you confirm that you can see something in `cleanString` even if you simply use `cleanString = RichTextBox1.Text`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace method worked for me (if anyone looking for this)

```
Dim input As String = "<img src='https://scontent-yyz1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t45.1600-4/43283458_6107883208189_8123813812978581504_n.png?_nc_cat=108&oh=1f88c51fa75c03ec2923655cc0b8e0ce&oe=5C14EE74' height='500'"
Dim output As String = input.Replace(""" height=""500""", "").Replace("<img src=""", "")
```

Answer (score 1):

**IF** what you're working on will always have the same structure then you could split the string.

```
Dim myDelims As String() = New String() { "src=" }
Dim url As String() = RichTextBox1.Text.Split(myDelims, StringSplitOptions.None)[1].Split(" ")[0].Replace(chr(39), "")
```

This looks for '*src=*' in the string input and takes the second index, then splits it again to remove any extra data after the url and finally removes the pesky quotes.

Note that splitting it by the quotation alone that if the HTML block for the image were to have something declared before it (ie style, class), your index would be wrong.  I'm making the assumption that you're looking specifically through image blocks from HTML.

This **will fail** if the second index doesn't exist, so you'll need to handle that event properly, possibly through a try catch block.

Answer (score 1):

Split the string on the " character.  You will get back an array of strings:

```
< img src=

https://scontent-yyz1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t45.1600-4/43283458_6107883208189_8123813812978581504_n.png?_nc_cat=108&oh=1f88c51fa75c03ec2923655cc0b8e0ce&oe=5C14EE74

 height=

500
```

The second one is what you want, right?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried regular expressions?

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Module Module1

    Sub Main()

        Dim pattern As String = "https?:\/\/(www\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)"
        Dim input As String = "<img src='https://scontent-yyz1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t45.1600-4/43283458_6107883208189_8123813812978581504_n.png?_nc_cat=108&oh=1f88c51fa75c03ec2923655cc0b8e0ce&oe=5C14EE74' height='500'"

        Dim regex As Regex = New Regex(pattern)
        Dim match As Match = regex.Match(input)

        If (match.Success) Then
            Console.WriteLine(match.Value)
        End If

    End Sub

End Module
```

Answer (score 0):

With [String.Split()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.String.Split);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%26f%3D255%26MSPPError%3D-2147217396&view=netframework-4.7.2). Split the original string using a know starting section (`"https:"`) and discarding all the other parts. This is hard-coding the logical position `(2)`

```
Dim parsed As String = "https:" &
    Input.Split(New String() {" ", "https:"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)(2).Trim(ChrW(34))
```

You could instead evaluate (filter) the string array and get the string you're interested in. In this case, the one that contains the sub-string `"png"`. It could be anything else you're looking for.

```
Dim output As String() = Input.Split(New String() {" ", "https:"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
Dim parsed As String = "https:" & output.Where(Function(item) item.Contains("png")).FirstOrDefault()
```